# how to define type for an imported function

Tags: typescript, d3.js, casting

I import `getAitoff` from `d3-geo-projection`, which is an extension lib of `d3-geo`. And projection function in `d3-geo` is well typed as `GeoProjection`, how can I declare type of `getAitoff` as `GeoProjection`?

GPT suggests me

```
import { geoAitoff } from 'd3-geo-projection';
import type { GeoProjection } from 'd3-geo';

const myProjection: GeoProjection = geoAitoff;
```

Is it the best way? (is it even correct?)
Is there any alternatives instead of adding a `.d.ts` file?

Comment: the best way is add `.d.ts` file, the method that provides from GPT is kind of workaround. If this function only been used in some specific files, it is enough, otherwise you should define its types by `.d.ts`

Comment: Honestly, the best way it to ask *the library maintainers to add types into their package*. Did work for me a couple of times.

Comment: Won't work here tho, maintainers bumped off to DefinetlyTyped where d3s types are (anyone could make types for it tho)

Comment: asked anyway on https://github.com/d3/d3-geo-projection/issues/202

Comment: For the moment I add a customized `.d.ts` file, I only use this very function for the moment in my personal project. So it's fine.